# The OOM killer kill process when there is enough memory available in linux

Tags: linux, kernel, yocto, out-of-memory

DotNET process got killed by OOM-Killer when ~150MB memory was available in system, and OOM min criteria is set 20MB.

Note: we are using Linux version 5.4.3-yocto-standard+g852f89dfab60

TCPBufferRcv.Rc invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x400dc0(GFP_KERNEL_ACCOUNT|__GFP_ZERO), order=0, oom_score_adj=0

CPU: 1 PID: 1263 Comm: TCPBufferRcv.Rc Tainted: G           O      5.4.3-yocto-standard+g852f89dfab60 #1

[104418.214488] Mem-Info:
[104418.218008] active_anon:162682 inactive_anon:22880 isolated_anon:0
[104418.218008]  active_file:139 inactive_file:495 isolated_file:0
[104418.218008]  unevictable:0 dirty:0 writeback:0 unstable:0
[104418.218008]  slab_reclaimable:1749 slab_unreclaimable:3627
[104418.218008]  mapped:14313 shmem:32870 pagetables:1284 bounce:0
[104418.218008]  free:36829 free_pcp:24 free_cma:32512
[104418.252416] Node 0 active_anon:650728kB inactive_anon:91520kB active_file:556kB inactive_file:1980kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB mapped:57252kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB shmem:131480kB writeback_tmp:0kB unstable:0kB all_unreclaimable? yes

[104418.276496] Normal free:146944kB min:20480kB low:25600kB high:30720kB active_anon:650728kB inactive_anon:91520kB active_file:624kB inactive_file:2236kB unevictable:0kB writepending:0kB present:1048576kB managed:1024476kB mlocked:0kB kernel_stack:1968kB pagetables:5136kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:96kB local_pcp:32kB free_cma:130048kB
[104418.305647] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0

[104418.309303] Normal: 4978*4kB (UMC) 3463*8kB (UMC) 1440*16kB (UC) 650*32kB (C) 191*64kB (UC) 62*128kB (C) 30*256kB (UC) 20*512kB (UC) 9*1024kB (UC) 2*2048kB (UC) 1*4096kB (U) 0*8192kB 0*16384kB 0*32768kB = 146944kB

[104418.328709] 33630 total pagecache pages
[104418.333180] 0 pages in swap cache
[104418.336716] Swap cache stats: add 0, delete 0, find 0/0
[104418.342292] Free swap  = 0kB
[104418.345403] Total swap = 0kB
[104418.348434] 262144 pages RAM
[104418.351560] 0 pages HighMem/MovableOnly
[104418.355753] 6025 pages reserved
[104418.359337] 81920 pages cma reserved

[104418.687766] oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_NONE,nodemask=(null),task=dotnet,pid=523,uid=0

[104418.696472] Out of memory: Killed process 523 (dotnet) total-vm:1602612kB, anon-rss:451100kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:0 pgtables:858112kB oom_score_adj:0

[104418.859439] oom_reaper: reaped process 523 (dotnet), now anon-rss:0kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB

[image]

Please help us to understand why OOM-killer is invoked by kernel when there was enough memory left to allocate?

Comment: For Experiment, we updated min value to 100MB(sysctl -w vm.min_free_kbytes=102400). and now kernel is invoking oom-killer when ~200MB is available.

[ 1944.097402] Normal free:344264kB min:102400kB low:128000kB high:153600kB active_anon:27200kB inactive_anon:10160kB active_file:640kB inactive_file:1072kB unevictable:519856kB writepending:0kB present:1048576kB managed:1024476kB mlocked:519856kB kernel_stack:1064kB pagetables:2344kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:500kB local_pcp:20kB free_cma:244708kB

[ 1944.129719] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0

[ 1944.133796] Normal: = 346324kB